# How to create PPTX when using POI XSLF?

Tags: java, apache-poi, xslf

When I create a PPTX with POI XSLF I get a blank slide:

```
XMLSlideShow ppt = new XMLSlideShow();
XSLFSlide slide = ppt.createSlide();
XSLFTextBox shape = slide.createTextBox();
XSLFTextParagraph p = shape.addNewTextParagraph();
XSLFTextRun r1 = p.addNewTextRun();
r1.setText("the");
r1.setFontColor(Color.blue);
r1.setFontSize(24);

OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream("d:/font.pptx");
ppt.write(out);
out.close();
```

Why is the slide blank without any text?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your text box has no anchor (position and size).

You can check the examples of POI how to add a text box:
[XSLF Examples - Tutorial 6](https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/poi/trunk/src/examples/src/org/apache/poi/xslf/usermodel/Tutorial6.java)

```
XSLFTextBox shape = slide.createTextBox();
shape.setAnchor(new Rectangle(x, y, width, height));
```

Comment: thanks  it works,I set anything without set the position.haha

Comment: Make the gray check mark left of the answer a green check mark (click on it).

Comment: that is done .thanks again.one more question,need your help.it is about image compress.you can see it on my question.

Comment: You should never edit your original question to ask a new one - just post a new question.

Comment: It must be in default example of POI site. easy to miss it. Thank you @TobiasLiefke